# Aggregating a large number of observations

Tags: excel, sum

I have around 250 000 observations and I need to sum them up so that in the first cell I have the sum of the first 300, in the second cell I have the sum of 301-601 and so on. This does not work just by writing `SUM(A1:A300)` and dragging because the second cell will be `SUM(A2:A301)`, the third `SUM(A3:A302)` and so on, while I want them to be `SUM(A301:A601)`, `SUM(A602:A902)` and so on.

If I have to do it manually for all 250 000 cells it will take me forever. So is there a shortcut?

Answer (score 1):

I much prefer `INDEX` over `OFFSET` because Offset is a volatile function, so something like this should work for you.  Using your provided explanation, in cell B1 and copied down:

```
=SUM(INDEX(A:A,1+(ROW(A1)-1)*300):INDEX(A:A,ROW(A1)*300))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can enter:

```
=SUM(OFFSET(A$1;(ROW(1:1)-1)*300;0;300))
```

and fill it down (or to the right if you have more columns)